# How to post label value?

Tags: php

Okay so I have a radio button on which my variable values get change through java-script.I am displaying that changed value in `<h>`Tag right.
Now I wants to post this `<h>` Tag value into database. I know `<h>`Tag is not a form element and other solution is using hidden input tag.
Here is my HTML Code:

```
<label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="delivery1" value="normal" checked><span class="label label-success">Regular Delivery</span></label><label>If you choose regular Delivery, it will take atleast 4 days time to deliver your product.(There will be no extra charges applied)</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="optradio" id="delivery2" value="fast"><span class="label label-danger">One Day Delivery</span></label>
              <label>If you choose One Day Delivery, product(s) will be delivered to you in 24 hours. (40 Rs Will be charged extra.) </label>
```

JS for that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#delivery1,#delivery2').change(function(){
    price = $('#price').text();
    finals = $('#finals').text();
    finals1 = $('#HIDDENPRICE').text();

    if($('#delivery2').is(':checked')) {
        price = (price)*1 + 40;
        finals=price;
      finals1=price;    
    } else {
        price = (price)*1 - 40;
        finals=price;
      finals1=price;  
    }
    $('#price').text(price);
    $('#finals').text(price);
    $('#HIDDENPRICE').text(price);
  });
});
  </script>
```

Displaying the value from radiobutton:

```
<h5><strong>Total</strong>
<h5 id="price" name="finalprice">


<?php
$finalprice=$item_total;
 echo $finalprice; 
 ?>
 </h5>
</h5>
```

Now I want this Tag value to be posted in database. Any Solution?

Comment: `"I know <h>Tag is not a form element and other solution is using hidden input tag."` - Doesn't that answer your own question?  I'm not clear on where you're stuck now.

Comment: Idk but I am doing code from last 10 hours constantly, so maybe my mind get struck, so just need a quick syntax for doing that...

Comment: For doing *what*?  If you don't know where you're stuck, then how do you know there's a problem at all?

Comment: Okay so if I change it into hidden field my code is : <input type="hidden" id="price" name="finalprice" value="<?php
$finalprice=$item_total;
 echo $finalprice; 
 ?>
" />  So I check it in my browser it is giving me something this type of result: <input type="hidden" id="price" name="finalprice" value="1200"></input>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a hidden input field : 
Look at this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#delivery1,#delivery2').change(function(){
    price = $('#price').text();
    if($('#delivery2').is(':checked')) {
        price = parseInt(price) + 40;

    } else {
        price = parseInt(price) - 40;
    }
    $('#price').text(price);
    $('#final_price').val(price);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rijink121/5vcvt527/4/

Comment: as always @Rijin codes only help me :P Thanks Mate!

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use the ajax call for this.
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post("test_post.php",{  finalprice: 'your final price',},
    function(data){
        alert(data); // the return data on success
    });
});


In the test_post.php you can write the database operation and also you can get the value in the post variable like
$_POST['finalprice']
```